# AWS Redshift Cluster Resize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, scale

I used the Elastic resize option to scale up our Redshift Data Warehouse from 2 to 4 (ds2.xlarge) nodes, the resize took only a few minutes.

I want to now scale our warehouse back to 2 nodes as we no longer need this much compute power.

It seems i cannot use the Elastic resize option to scale down the instance but now need to use the classic resize option, which according to AWS can take hours, is this the case?

Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: From what I can see in the documentation, should should be able to double or halve the number of nodes, so you should be able to move from 4-node to 2-node. How much data do you have stored? Will it still fit in a 2-node cluster?

Comment: Thanks John, Yes the data will fit in a 2 node cluster, i just scaled up to 4 nodes in order to do some backloading of data through the night.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, went with the Classic resize option, took 3 hours.

Comment: how do we do classic resize for existing cluster using commands